# how to properly insert the date into the mysqldump command

Tags: mysql, bash

I'm trying to insert the date into the .sql file name when making a backup.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mysqldump --databases data > data-backup-$(date "+%D--%T").sql
```

But I get this error as output

```
./backup.sh: line 2: data-backup-$(date "+%D--%T").sql: No such file or directory
```

But when I exec the same command but without the date inserted there is no such error.

Comment: How do you run your script?

Comment: I'v tried with `bash backup.sh`, `./backup.sh` and by typing the command directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`date "+%D--%T"` outputs something like `12/18/21--00:19:21`.

`/` is not allowed in file names with Linux/Unix.